# How to print the Original List again after printing the Ascending Order List?

Tags: java, arrays

Can you help me with how can I fix my code?

My goal is:

> The user will enter how many numbers they want to enter.
> They will enter the numbers they want until the limit that they input (1).
> My program will Print the Original List.
> Next line, my program will Print the Ascending Order of the numbers.
> Next line, my program Again will Print the Original List.

Basically, this is how the output should be:

> Original List: 55 3 95 10 7
> Ascending Order: 3 7 10 55 95
> Original List: 55 95 10 7

This is my code:

```java
// ASKING THE USER TO INPUT NUMBERS
System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
int userInput = sc.nextInt();

int[] numbersEntered = new int[userInput]; //declare an array

for (int counter = 0; counter < userInput; counter++) {
    System.out.print("Enter Next Number: ");
    numbersEntered[counter] = sc.nextInt();

    // PRINTING THE ORIGINAL LIST
    System.out.println("The Numbers You Entered Are:");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < userInput; counter++) {
        System.out.print(numbersEntered[counter] + " ");

        // PRINTING THE ASCENDING LIST USING ARRAYS.SORT();
        Arrays.sort(numbersEntered);
        System.out.println("\nThe Numbers You Entered in Ascending Order:");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < userInput; counter++) {
            System.out.print(numbersEntered[counter] + " ");

            // PRINTING AGAIN THE ORIGINAL LIST
            System.out.println("\nOriginal List");
            for (int counter = 0; counter < userInput; counter++) {
                System.out.print(numbersEntered[counter] + " ");
```

But my problem here is that, whenever I tried to print the Last Original List, It keeps copying the answer on the Ascending List. I think the problem is because of the `Arrays.sort()` that I used before the last Original List, but I don't know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.sort` sorts the array *in place*, this means that it changes the the order of the elements of the array you pass in, hence *losing* the original order.

One way to fix this is to create a copy of the original, and sort the copy instead:

```java
int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(numbersEntered, numbersEntered.length);
// PRINTING THE ASCENDING LIST USING ARRAYS.SORT();
Arrays.sort(copy);
System.out.println("\nThe Numbers You Entered in Ascending Order:");
for (int counter = 0; counter < userInput; counter++) {
    System.out.print(copy[counter] + " "); // print the copy

    // PRINTING AGAIN THE ORIGINAL LIST
    System.out.println("\nOriginal List");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < userInput; counter++) {
        System.out.print(numbersEntered[counter] + " "); // print the original
```

Comment: big thank you!!, i've been trying to think of another way on how I can print it without modifying the original list but I never thought about creating a new copy. You were a really big help!